# Non-ARC to ARC: double asterik

Tags: ios, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I have following non-ARC code

```
int sortMidiEvent(void* v1, void* v2) {
    MidiEvent **ev1 = (MidiEvent**)v1;
    MidiEvent **ev2 = (MidiEvent**)v2;
    MidiEvent *event1 = *ev1;
    MidiEvent *event2 = *ev2;

    if (event1.startTime == event2.startTime) {
        return event1.eventFlag - event2.eventFlag;
    }
    else {
        return event1.startTime - event2.startTime;
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to ARC. What should I do?

Can I change to the following?

```
int sortMidiEvent(void* v1, void* v2) {

    MidiEvent *event1 = (__bridge MidiEvent *) v1;
    MidiEvent *event2 = (__bridge MidiEvent *) v2;

    if (event1.startTime == event2.startTime) {
        return event1.eventFlag - event2.eventFlag;
    }
    else {
        return event1.startTime - event2.startTime;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why we need pointer to pointer in non-ARC?

Comment: Whether you'll need a pointer to a pointer or not depends on how whatever calls `sortMidiEvent` passes the arguments. ARC or non-ARC, the number of pointer indirections must be the same. (Maybe you should use an Objective-C sorting function instead of plain C?)

Comment: Why do u think it isn't an ARC code? It's seems like u writing in C (but dream on Objective-C)